# Shared Preferences initial declaration

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm new to android. i wanted to initialize a shared preference.
i just need an auto increment id. i search many shared preferences and i cant understand their explanation.

i just wanted a simple initialization of a number.

for example,

```
key = RemID and initial value of that key is 0.
```

i want to initialize that at the first time only, not at every launch of my app

and i will be using that value and increment and store it back.

please share some thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest using the default value parameter of `SharedPreferences`'s `get*` methods.

For example:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("counters",
                                                       Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// increment a counter
int counter = prefs.getInt("counter", 0); // Using '0' for the default value
prefs.edit().putInt("counter", counter+1).apply();
```

Comment: sir orip, where should i put that first line of code? in what activity? is the first line. already initializes the "counters"?

Comment: The first line is how you create your SharedPreferences instance. You can, for example, set it to a field in the activity's `onCreate`. It creates a shared preferences file named "counters" if it doesn't exist - if it does, it loads the preferences.

Comment: okay sir. i will try this out. thanks a lot. be right back. if this thing work out. i give you a plus!

Answer (score 0):

Hi below is may be help for you

```
private void setShared() {
        SharedPreferences records = getSharedPreferences(
                LoginActivity.USER_RECORD, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = records.edit();

        int count = nImageUrl.size();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            prefEditor.putInt(ID + savedPhotosCount, Singleton.instanse.getCustomerID(mCustomerIndex));
            prefEditor.putString(FILE_PATH + savedPhotosCount, nImageUrl.get(i));
            prefEditor.putString(DESCRIPTION + savedPhotosCount, captionText.get(i));
            savedPhotosCount++;
            prefEditor.putInt(SAVED_PHOTOS_COUNT, savedPhotosCount);
        }
        prefEditor.commit();
    }
```

First declare the variable

```
  int savedPhotosCount = 0;
```

Every time the id was incremented.

Comment: hi sir ramesh, can you please explain the first line? where is the initial declarion?

Comment: before oncreate function.Like Below

int savedPhotosCount = 0;
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
int sharedPrefValue;
```

then in the onCreate method,

```
sharedPrefValue=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getInt("sharedPrefValue", 0);
```

and then,

```
sharedPrefValue++;
```

PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putInt("sharedPrefValue", sharedPrefValue).commit();